# Cannot log in to Ubuntu Forums and cannot contact administrator

Tags: login, launchpad, administrator, ubuntu-forums

I have a dilemma. I can't log in to Ubuntu Forums using my user name. When I try to recover my password. It says my email is not in the system. It says I can contact the administrator. When I click on the link to contact the administrator, it says I have to be logged in.

I believe I was in the midst of setting up and account after signing in with Launchpad. The process never completed, so I don't have a password. I'm pretty sure the user name I'm trying to use does not belong to anyone else.